# Google maps: отключение alert

Tags: google-maps-api, javascript

Вопрос такой: если ключ не найден, то подключенный js гугла выдает alert.
Как просто проигнорировать этот alert и просто не отображать карту, либо перехватить каким-то образом этот alert и например положить в переменную результат подключения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only thing you can do to prevent the message being displayed is to 
> overwrite the Javascript alert() function with your own alert() function 
> which doesn't display anything to the user, before calling the API 
> loader.
>         function alert() {}

[Источник](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/a077ca11acca7743?pli=1).

Comment: Или проще говоря: function alert() {} перед подключением api.

Спасибо! :)

Comment: не хотел чужую идею выдавать за свою ))

Comment: Правильный подход ))

Я даже сделал так: сначала сохраняю старую функцию, а после переопределния восстанавливаю старую. Алерта нет, а свои алерты при тестировании работают ))
Все отлично))